# Magento 2:Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions

Tags: magento2

I try to import product using csv file in localhost of wamp server but show error in Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions
I add product images in pub/media/import

Answer (score 1):

This issue only comes due to below following reasons:

1. Uploaded images are corrupted.

2. Path given in sheet and uploaded images path are different.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem but solved as in

1. put your all images at **pub/media/images/catalog/product/CUSTOM_DIR/1.jpg**
   eg: /var/www/html/ocean-tableware/pub/media/catalog/product/lucaris
2. In csv put base_image path as **/CUSTOM_DIR/1.jpg**
   Eg: [image]
3. While import from backend put path 'pub/media/import/
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same images issue while importing product via CSV.

Check the fixed answer. Hope it help.

[Magento 2 product import won't import images](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109066/magento-2-product-import-wont-import-images/279743#279743)